# Why Backbone js call multiple request at same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

Please give me solutions how i can get single call of put , delete or get request. when i load below script. it get three ajax call of put , delete and get request at the same time.

```
 var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: '/test.php',
        defaults: {
            name: '',
            email: ''
        }
    });
     var user = new UserModel({id: 1});
    // Notice that we haven't set an `id`
    var userDetails = {
        name: 'Thomas',
        email: 'thomasalwyndavis@gmail.com'
    };
    // Because we have not set a `id` the server will call
    // POST /user with a payload of {name:'Thomas', email: 'thomasalwyndavis@gmail.com'}
    // The server should save the data and return a response containing the new `id`
    user.save(userDetails, {
        success: function (user) {
            console.log('save call back');
        }
    })

    user.destroy({
        success: function () {
            console.log('Destroyed');
        }
    });

     user.fetch({
        success: function (user) {
            console.log(user.toJSON());
        }
    })
```

Comment: just comment the operation that you do not want to run?

Comment: how i can call separately save , destroy and fetch event ?

Comment: just like you separate any other events (if you ever did): put them into the functions and then call these functions anytime you want the particular operation to be executed

Comment: This is backbone js code . so when i intialise the object on backbone model then instalty fired save , destroy and fetch event by calling this code :    
var user = new UserModel({id: 1});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code fragment mixes initialisation, creation, and usage. The model initialisation is

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/test.php',
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        email: ''
    }
});
```

The code above describes the user model and should be run once in the page/application lifetime.

The following is the creation of user model instance:

```
 var user = new UserModel({id: 1});
```

But more relevant for your example will probably be

```
 var user = new UserModel({
    id: 1,
    name: 'Thomas',
    email: 'thomasalwyndavis@gmail.com'
 });
```

Then you can do some operations with the created user: save, destroy, or fetch. But not all of them at once. For example, you may delete it when user clicks the button on the page:

```
$('.delete-button').click(function () {
    user.destroy({
        success: function () {
            console.log('Destroyed');
        }
    });
});
```

So all these code fragments are typically in different parts of the application and serves different purpose - in your code example they are all in the same place so the example is messy and its purpose is not clear.